# Unable to import Chunk theme in Cordova application

Tags: java, android, templates, chunk-templates

I am trying to use Chunk template engine in a Hybrid Mobile application. I am able to replace tags however I am not able to load the theme and need some help.

```
String templatePath = "src/com/test/xml/plugin/util/themes";
String themeLayers = "";
Theme theme = new Theme(templatePath, themeLayers);
Chunk c = theme.makeChunk("test");

c.set("fptime","testa");
return(c.toString());
```

In the above code when I do `theme.makeChunk("test"`) it does not work and the generated Chunk does not contain anything.

FYI-- My Chunk file name is test.cxml

Also, I would like to know should I use chunk or should I use any other template engine.?

Thanks in advance,
Vishesh.

Answer (score 0):

Android is a bit different from typical server-side usage.  In a server-side app, theme resources can be packaged into a jar file and then become accessible on the classpath.

On Android, the app is deployed a bit differently, and code and resources are more strictly separated.

Theme files (ie, templates) are typically packaged as assets in the build step, and can be loaded using the provided AndroidTemplates provider.  This special theme provider is initialized with the app's Context so it can locate the template resources.

There is an example on the Chunk homepage here:

http://www.x5software.com/chunk/examples/ChunkExample?example=android

Place test.cxml file in assets/themes/test.cxml

```
AndroidTemplates loader = new AndroidTemplates(getBaseContext());
Theme theme = new Theme(loader);
Chunk chunk = theme.makeChunk("test.cxml");
c.set("fptime", "testa");
return c.toString();
```